# JSTL - Generate compile error for certain DynamicAttribute

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, taglib

I am using DynamicAttribute in jstl. It will probably catch every attribute not declared in the tld. Is there any way to generate a compile error only for certain not present attributes?

Let's say I want to disallow the use of `foo="bar"` attribute but allow the dynamic usage of `data-*="bar"` being `*` any string specified in the HTML 5 data attribute spec.
If there is no such feature how would I achieve the same result using the current java jstl spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering this feature impossible to be achieved, if I am wrong anyone is encouraged to answer then I will accept.